# Missing app store icon in App Store Connect and TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight, app-store-connect

I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour with App Store Connect and Test Flight.

The build is being processed correctly and even passes beta review. I have the 1024*1024 icon included in my bundle.

Somehow the app icon appears blank ( see attached images ),

[image]

[image]

Comment: To add your App Store icon to an asset catalog located in the Xcode project, make sure you have added the app icon in here https://imgur.com/NkgUtIG

Answer (score 1):

Just drag 1024*1024 icon to App Store Icon. It independence with Assets (your bundle).

Comment: you can't do that since Xcode 10. App icons should be included in the bundle.

Comment: I think General App Information it's not related Xcode.